# npm install command is showing bunch of error - Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I am tying to install a package

```
npm install vuejs-image-gallery
```

but when I run this commandon the terminal I got this bunch of errro message :=(

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR! Found: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^5.16.0 || ^6.1.0 || ^7.2.0" from @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@5.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!     dev @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@"^5.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">= 4.12.1" from babel-eslint@10.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-eslint
npm ERR!     dev babel-eslint@"^10.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (eslint-config-airbnb-base, eslint-plugin-import, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">=7.5.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.25.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=7.5.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/hello/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hello/.npm/_logs/2022-10-21T06_05_43_010Z-debug-0.log
```

I also try to install that package using this command:

```
npm install vuejs-image-gallery legacy-peer-deps
```

This command is install the package but on my vue application it's saying:

> can't find the moudle

**So, Something is wrong. Would you please tell me what is wrong by check that error message?**

Comment: it states you should use `--legacy-peer-deps` not `legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: use --legacy-peer-deps as instead of legacy-peer-deps `npm install vuejs-image-gallery --legacy-peer-deps` and also once installed please check the output is that showing like `added 1 package`

Comment: Ok. let me check it.

Comment: I got this after run the command: https://codeshare.io/YLKrgN

Comment: Now, I use `import Gallery from "vuejs-image-gallery";` and it's showing me `app.js:156509 Error: Cannot find module 'vuejs-image-gallery'`

Comment: I recommend using yarn/PNPM for proper error messages/performance. NPM is quite behind in my opinion. Those logs are not helping too.